# Java compiler error about this annotation?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotations

The hibernate cascade annotation value "org.hibernate" is conflicting with the variable "org", it's taking "org" as variable name, not part of the package name. I am getting error:

```
.java:[14,16] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable hibernate
[ERROR] location: class java.lang.Object
[ERROR] Foo.java:[14,50] an enum annotation value must be an enum constant
```

It seems to be a generic Java compiler bug. Should be reproducible when you define an object variable which is the same as the first package element.

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

public class Foo {
    Object org;

    @OneToMany
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    Object foo;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    Object foo2;
}
```

Comment: If you should be able to reproduce it, it would be a good idea to do so in a short but complete program - and post that here instead of something with a Hibernate dependency :)

Comment: I guess the sample code I provided is simpler than defining a bunch of custom classes to show the problem. You would need to define custom annotation which takes a custom class as its attribute value :), and a couple more classes to present the case.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/6.doc.html#20569) is definition of how Java determines the meaning of a name.

Comment: This happens only when you use full class name as attribute value of an annotation. Using the same class name to define a java variable works.